# different login routes and login views for student and admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

*Every laravel newbie struggles with multi auth, I am no exception*

I am trying to make student management system. There will two different routs for admin `admin/login` and for student `student/login`.

The student can't register itself, but he will be registered by admin.

So a student has only access to `student/dashboard`, registration of students will be done by the admin on `admin/dashboard`.

Below is the detail what I have already done:

1. created migration for both admin and student.
2. created guard for both admin and student.
3. modified login controller and added adminLogin and studentLogin methods.
4. modified `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware

**Config/auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],
        'web-admin'=>[
            'driver'=>'session',
            'provider'=>'admin',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'students',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Student::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

'passwords' => [
        'students' => [
            'provider' => 'students',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

***LoginController.php***

```
lass LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

        $this->middleware('guest:web-admin')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:students')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showAdminLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login', ['url' => 'admin']);
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'admin_id'   => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['admin_id' => $request->adminid, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('admin_id', 'remember'));
    }

    public function showStudentLoginForm()
    {
        return view('student.login', ['url' => 'student']);
    }

    public function studentLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'roll_no'   => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('writer')->attempt(['roll_no' => $request->roll_no, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/student/dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('roll_no', 'remember'));
    }

}
```

**RedirectAuthenticated.php**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
           if('web_admin'==='$guard'){
               return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
           }
           return redirect('/admin/login');
        }
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if('students'==='$guard'){
                return redirect('/student/dashboard');
            }
            return redirect('/student/login');
         }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have created two folders in the view, student and admin. They both have two files. login.blade.php and dashboard.blade.php

What laravel does it it shows login, and register under auth folder.

I want to give two routes one for `/admin/login` which return `admin.login` view.

Same for student `/student/login` which return `student.login` view.

I want to remove `/register` route and make the link to available on `admin dashboard` , there will be no admin register link.

Also restrict the user from accessing admin area.

**I don't want the whole code, just help me steps and way that I should follow or changes I have to make **

Comment: Your question is too broad. Try to find and follow tutorial like this https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel. When stuck, ask one specific question at a time. If you have many questions, post them separately

Comment: @Yohanes I was following the same, but got confused after this, I mean confused how to redirect to different routes to different views also implement restrictions.

Comment: Try to understand how routes and controllers work instead of just copy-pasting the tutorial. In a nutshell, you just need to create separate controllers and routes for admin like in this tutorial https://medium.com/hello-laravel/multiple-authentication-system-laravel-5-4-ac94c759638a

Comment: where is your route file

Comment: That's what I want to know How to setup the routes and return the view. It has Route::auth() which implements everything login register and password resets, I want this to map the views I have.

Comment: If I make an admincontroller and studentcontroller and give both showlogin and login methods. In login method I implement attempt login. And make a middleware for admin to restrict rest of admincontroller methods. Would that be better? Will that work? Without running php artisan make:auth

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it. I didn't use `php artisan make:auth`, instead I did it from scratch.
 Created a fresh project, deleted `User.php` and the migration.
Created models `Student.php` and `Admin.php` along with migrations and controllers.
`php artisan make:model Student -mc` 
`php artisan make:model Admin -mc`

After than I created guards, I deleted default guard (I don't know It was right to do so, but I felt that if there is no need of default guard and also it was using users table so I deleted).
Here is **config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'student'=>[
            'driver'=>'session',
            'provider'=>'students'
        ],
        'admin'=>[
            'driver'=>'session',
            'provider'=>'admins'     
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'students'=>[
            'driver'=>'eloquent',
            'model'=>App\Student::class,
        ],
        'admins'=>[
            'driver'=>'eloquent',
            'model'=>App\Admin::class,
        ]
```

So I have two guards *student* and *admin*.
Here is the admin model  **Admin.php**

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname','admin_id', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

and model Student **Student.php**

```
class Student extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname','admin_id', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

After this I modified **AdminController.php**

```
class AdminsController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $guard = 'admin';

    public function showLogin(){
        return view('admin.login');
    }
    public function dashboard(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'admin_id' => 'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:8', 
        ]);

        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['admin_id'=>$request['admin_id'], 'password'=>$request['password']])){
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

Then I created routes **Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/admin','AdminsController@showLogin');
Route::get('/student','StudentsController@showLogin');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminsController@dashboard');
Route::get('/student','StudentsController@showLogin');
Route::post('/admin/login','AdminsController@login');
Route::post('/student/login','StudentsController@login');
```

Now, at this time login works. I still need to do a lot. If any suggestion, I welcome that, please comment below.